# Is it possible to prevent a stop iteration when using a generator with keras tuner in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been having some trouble with the random search tuner from Keras. By default, you can just implement the x train and y train, however due to the nature of my data I have to iterate over a list first, and give the tuner a file one by one. When I was building CNNs this wasn't an issue since I only needed to go over the data once. However, since the Random Search is iteratively trying to find the best solution over the n trials, it can't do that in this case because I always get a stop iteration from using a generator. Here is the code below.

```
tuner = RandomSearch(build_model,
                     objective="accuracy",
                     overwrite=True,
                     #project_name="AC1",
                     max_trials = 5,
                     executions_per_trial=5
                    )

def generate_arrays_from_file(x_train, y_train):
    for x, y in zip(x_train, y_train):
        yield (x, y)
                
tuner.search(generate_arrays_from_file(X_train, Y_train), verbose=0)
```

For reference the shape of the data is (388, 96, 36, 36, 36). My issue in this case, is that my model that I am hypertuning requires 1 file of shape (96, 36, 36, 36) at a time as its a 3D CNN. Basically, I have 388 data points, in each data point there are 96 cubic arrays with a corresponding label (0 or 1). My question in this case, is there a way to prevent the stopiteration from occurring, or is there a different approach I can take?

I haven't tried unpacking the data points (change 388, 96 to only 37248), so there is also that to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Keras and don't know whether this makes sense in your exact use case but you can yield indefinitely by going back to the start of the zip each time you exhaust it:

```py
def generate_arrays_from_file(x_train, y_train):
    while True:  # or for _ in range(388):
        for x, y in zip(x_train, y_train):
            yield (x, y)
```